# Plotting in colour in IDL

Tags: colors, plot, idl-programming-language

I have trouble plotting different colours in IDL. If I do the following:

```
loadct, 13
plot, x, y, color=n
```

No matter what value I put for n, I can only get different shades of red. How can I plot in other colours?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question:

I managed to plot in colours using the [getcolor](http://www.arm.ac.uk/~csj/idl/getcolor.pro) function. I find it much more straightforward than doing it normally.

```
colors = [getcolor('white'), getcolor('red'), getcolor('blue'), getcolor('green'), getcolor('magenta'), getcolor('cyan')]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are in decomposed color mode; change to indexed color mode with:

```
device, decomposed=0
```